# Format date to MM/DD/YYYY, remove seconds & miliseconds, and convert from military to standard time SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a field `Run_time`. I would like to Format date to `MM/DD/YYYY`, remove seconds & miliseconds, and convert from military to standard time SQL.
For example:

```
Select Run_time from Table
```

The current output is such:

```
2018-06-04 15:18:56.333
```

I would like the output to look like the following:

```
06/04/2018 3:18pm
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

thank you!
~Adam

Comment: the `AM/PM` will be dealt by the front-end application. SQL treats a date as a date no matter what format it is

Comment: You know the final end of life for Sql Server 2008 is only a year away right? After July 2019 it will no longer get _any_ updates... not even critical security patches. Upgrading this server **NOW** should be your top priority. Additionally, Sql Server 2012 and later have a `FORMAT()` function that make this problem very easy to solve.

Comment: You should avoid changing a date/time format in SQL Server; when you convert it to a string, you lose a lot of things, e.g. they are no longer sortable or comparable. The best way to deal with this is to format the date in the front end application or in your report.

Answer (score 2):

Adam,

The correct place to format dates would be in the presentation layer, namely the front end application. However, since the question wasn't where to do it, rather *how* to do it in t-sql, we'll answer that question as-is.

There are many formats in which you can convert a date in SQL Server (reference below), though for this exact result, you'll need to concatenate 2 of them, as the one which provides dates in a mm/dd/yyyy format doesn't have the hh:mm AM/PM format to go with it. Here's the t-sql:

```
SELECT  
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), Run_time ,101) + ' '+ LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(19), Run_time ,0),7))
FROM Table
```

Here's a link to the page which shows you the different conversion formats in t-sql:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017